# Get values from int, then save in array and calculate modulo

Tags: java, arrays, int, modulo

I need to write a program which should read a few numbers from an int, then save the values in array and to calculate the modulo of the numbers I read in.

I made this so far, but I have no idea how to store int in array, or how to calculate modulo of an array. Hope someone can help.

```
public class modulo {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    int counter = 0;
    int r = 0;
    int modus;
    int numbers;
    int[] n;

    Out.print("How many numbers you want to calculate: ");
    r = In.readInt ();
    Out.print("With which number you want to calculate the modulo: ");
    modus = In.readInt ();

        while (counter != r) {
            counter++;
            Out.print("Put the " + counter + ".number: ");
            numbers = In.readInt ();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to `new` your array, otherwise you'd get `NullPointerException`. Since you already know your array size, this is what you will write after you've read `r` from the input:

```
int[] n = new n[r]
```

Then, you need a `for` loop to read from the input and save it to the array.

As for your next  question, here is the answer.

[How can I implement a modulus on a list of numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32543901/how-can-i-implement-a-modulus-on-a-list-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are not dynamic, meaning, once given a size it will stay that size. For example "int[] arr = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}; or int[] arr = new int[5];"

For this particular example you may want to do the second declaration of array that I gave you as an example because this allows you to later declare the size of the array(after you get your input from how many numbers you want to calculate"

after this you ask with which number you want to calculate the array to. This can be done using a for loop and then doing something like:

`for(int i = 0; i < arr.lenght; i++){
new_arr[i]= arr[i]%mod; //this stores each operation into a new array.
}`

hope this helps!

Comment: But how to define new_arr?

Comment: sorry for the very late response. You can ask for the user to input the amount of numbers he wants to measure this will make your array "dynamic"(not trully but at least you can have control over how many numbers can be entered into it).

Answer (score 0):

```
I do this, still the same

public class modulo {

public static void main (String[] args) {

    int counter = 0;
    int zahlen = 0;
    int modus;
    int numbers;
    int[] n = new int[zahlen];
    int [] new_arr = new int [0];






    Out.print("Wie viele Zahlen moechten Sie berechnen: ");
    zahlen = In.readInt ();
    Out.print("Mit welcher Zahl moechten Sie Modulo berechnen: ");
    modus = In.readInt ();


        while (counter != zahlen) {
            counter++;
            Out.print("Geben sie die " + counter + ".Zahl ein: ");
            numbers = In.readInt ();

        }

        for(int i = 0; i < n.length; i++){
               new_arr[i]= n[i]%modus; 
               Out.print(new_arr);
        }








    }
```

}